# Using sous vide to warm canned vegetables

Tags: vegetables, sous-vide

Has anyone attempted to plunge a can of vegetables into the sous vide bath given it is already vacuum packed? I would, of course, take off the label.

Comment: Of course, canned vegetables are already cooked.  So, there is not problem warming them, if that is your intention.

Comment: Just make sure it does not [explode](https://youtu.be/rtDQXo4T5GM).

Comment: Also, when you open the can, beware the heat pressurized contents do not burn you. Pv=nRT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law

Answer (score 1):

If you were to do that it would be closer to poaching the vegetables assuming that most canned vegetables are in a liquid and the water in and out the can would be kept below the boiling point.

You would have to be carful of built up pressure by the heat (should be fine since you're not sous viding in boiling water nor is there air in the can.)